# Refactoring a JS Function

Tags: javascript, function, refactoring

I need some opinions on how could i re-type this function without jQuery in a more efficently,any ideeas?

```
function matchedCards() {
  $(".card").on("click",function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("open show")) {return; }
    $(this).toggleClass("open show");
    openedCards.push($(this));
    beginGame = true;
  });
}
```

Comment: it not that hard , just read the documentation of javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking something like the follows:

```
'use strict';
const cards =document.querySelectorAll('.card')

function handleEvent() {
    if(this.classList.contains('open') || this.classList.contains('show')) {
        return;
    }
    this.classList.toggle('open')
    this.classList.toggle('show')
    openedCards.push(this)
    beginGame = true
}

cards.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', handleEvent)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `cards` can be multiple, you can do something like this.
I also added an `onclick` event for each card:

```js
var openedCards = [];
var beginGame = false;

function matchedCards() {
  const cards = (document).getElementsByClassName("card");
  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    if (!cards.item(i).className.includes("open show")) {
      cards.item(i).className += " open show";
      openedCards.push(cards.item(i));
      beginGame = true;
    }
  }
  console.log(openedCards, beginGame);
}

function toggleCard(element) {
  if (!element.className.includes("open show")) {
    element.className += " open show";
    openedCards.push(element);
    beginGame = true;
  } else {
    const idx = element.className.indexOf("open show");
    const className = element.className.slice(0, idx) + element.className.slice(idx+9);
    element.className = className.trim();
  }
  console.log(openedCards, beginGame);
}
```

```css
.show {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" onclick="toggleCard(this)">1</div>
<div class="card" onclick="toggleCard(this)">2</div>
<div class="card open show" onclick="toggleCard(this)">3</div>

<button onClick="matchedCards()">Show</button>
```